# Getting redirecting server IP

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, ip

```
A (client) --> B (gateway application) --> C (core application)
A (client) ------------------------------> C (core application)
```

As shown above, A can come to C directly or via B. 
When A comes to C via B, that becomes a special case. For this, I am trying to find out where the request is coming in based off the IP address of B.

But when I give

```
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

it is returning me the IP address of A. 
Is there any way I can get the IP address of B.

Or is there any other better way for C to know that the request is coming directly or via B. 
Option not allowed: Any parameter in URL

Options tried, and not working:

```
HttpServletRequest getRemoteAddr()
ServletRequest getRemoreAddr()
getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")
```

Comment: How does B forward to C? Can B add a custom `X-VIA-B: b_ip_addr` header to the incoming request?

Comment: Alex, B does a sendRedirect. I do not want to add anything to header since it can be spoofed by a man in the middle attack.

Comment: Add an hmac/signed value using a key known only to B & C

Comment: I will look up what a HMAC is. But the question is, how would I pass the key around? I cannot pass it via the url bar.

Comment: The application on B/C would need to be know the key, stored in a config file or the like.

Comment: Alex, I can have them in config files of both applications. But how would I send the key from B to C for C to validate it. Edit: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" Never faced this before.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `B(Gateway application)`,you will have to add new header or append it's IP to "`X-FORWARDED-FOR`" header.It's normal, For Ex:- In our case we do below in `nginx`,which sits in front of `tomcat`.

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: RE, but with a man-in-the-middle attack, wouldn't the hacker be able to spoof these headers?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/can-i-trust-the-source-ip-of-an-http-request